# Increase the radius of one scatterplot point set and keep others smaller

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have one c3js based scatterplot, which consists many sets, and I am trying to make one of the sets larger than all the others in the plot. In the attached picture, blue dots would be larger, and grey dots will be a smaller size [image: plot example]

I know I can modify the circle radius using the `point` setting, but I don't know if there's a d3js equation that can be used in this case.

Thanks in advance

Code sample is below. There are more columns, omitted for brevity.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['main_sample', 0.894521525, 0.822982385, 0.918882717,  0.943894341, ...]
        ['s2',  1.136678317,1.063005349,0.969992506,0.915937076, ...]
        ['s3', 0.786620274,0.607559441,1.060137152, ...]
     ],
    names: {
            'main_sample': 'test',
            's2': '',
            's3': '',
           },
    type: 'scatter',
    colors:{
            'main_sample': '#000099',
            's2': '#D8D8D8',
            's3': '#D8D8D8',
      }
  },
  legend: {
        show: false
     }
});
```

Comment: Open the dev tools with F12 and inspect the dots - you need to find something to target them with in a d3 selector. If its anything like this random example from the web at http://bl.ocks.org/weiglemc/6185069 then the only differentiator is the rgb color - hard to hit with a selector.

Comment: Or can you assign a dummy class via .attr("class", "dummyclass") then target that class in a selector? Post your code or a cut-down version.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I added the code with less data points and shorter columns. The only thing distinguishing the columns are their IDs, main_sample would have the ID exposed and all the other ones will not be shown to the final user (legends are hidden, and blank names for the tooltips).

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I will check your suggestions, thanks a lot.